# What's the difference between Linux SOCK_RAW and SOCK_STREAM?

Tags: c, linux, networking, ip

I've been studying networking with c code and cryptography lately and upon pondering random questions I stumbled across a block of code that's used for packet sniffing and I had a question on the actual socket that gets used in the function `recvfrom()`. The socket gets initialized through the following sock function `rawSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 0)`.

I understand that `SOCK_STREAM` and `SOCK_RAW` are macros that represent an integer; but the question isn't about the values, it's about the results.

When would I use `SOCK_STREAM` over `SOCK_RAW` and vice versa?

I understand basic client and server communications using `SOCK_STREAM`. I'm working with C and in Linux

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14774668/694576

Comment: Simplified you can say SOCK_STREAM uses TCP/IP, that is TCP over IP. SOCK_RAW is IP only, what ever you use/implement.

Comment: Related^2: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13333794/694576

Comment: Beginner level answer: you'd never use `SOCK_RAW`. Expert answer: ... except...

Comment: Except when you want to sniff a network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html).

For the prototype

```
int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
```

The types can be

```
   SOCK_STREAM     Provides sequenced, reliable, two-way, connection-
                   based byte streams.  An out-of-band data transmission
                   mechanism may be supported.
```

or

```
   SOCK_RAW        Provides raw network protocol access.
```

In one line, `SOCK_STREAM` is for connection oriented sockets, where the underlying OS creates and manages the headers for L4 (TCP), L3 and L2. OTOH `SOCK_RAW` provides more fine-grained control over header and packet construction, where the user has to construct and supply the headers and can also manage the contents.

To elaborate:

> Sockets of type SOCK_STREAM are full-duplex byte streams.  They do
>          not preserve record boundaries.  A stream socket must be in a
>          connected state before any data may be sent or received on it.  A
>          connection to another socket is created with a connect(2) call.  Once
>          connected, data may be transferred using read(2) and write(2) calls
>          or some variant of the send(2) and recv(2) calls.  When a session has
>          been completed a close(2) may be performed.  Out-of-band data may
>          also be transmitted as described in send(2) and received as described
>          in recv(2).

and

> SOCK_RAW sockets allow sending of datagrams to
>          correspondents named in sendto(2) calls.  Datagrams are generally
>          received with recvfrom(2), which returns the next datagram along with
>          the address of its sender.

Comment: Here is what you dropped from your last quote: "*`SOCK_DGRAM` and*" ;-)

Comment: @alk That's why I put the source in the first line itself. :)

Comment: So the follow up question probably would be: "What is the difference between `SOCK_DGRAM` and `SOCK_RAW`?"